# Multiple Stripe Webhooks for checkout.session.completed from various Joomla components

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-4.x, stripe, webhooks

Scenario

- Site has OSMembership for subscriptions
- Site has RSForms Pro for registering for in person / virtual courses
- Site has J2Store for some miscellaneous products

In Stripe, I've set up two checkout.session.completed webhooks for OSMembership and RSForms (J2Store doesn't currently have notes regarding a webhook).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59995848/stripe-handle-multiple-webhooks indicates

- Both webhooks would be triggered, but only one needs to fire.
- Workaround is a page needs to be created for the checkout.session.completed webhook (a page separate to the OSMembership and RSForms Pro webhook destinations)

1. The new webhook page retrieves the Stripe Session ID
2. It looks at the metadata coming back from the session
3. It identifies the initiating component
4. It redirects the webhook to the appropriate component webhook page to then pass the Stripe session data across to the correct endpoint and in turn complete the transaction in the correct place.

Has anyone implemented a solution like this before in Joomla?

Know what to look at in the session array to identify which component to send things back to?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in the posted link to do a var_dump on what is coming back from Stripe to see if there is something you can use to identify the sender.

Comment: There's information coming back - but it's then what to do with it. https://webhookrelay.com/ was suggested as a way to do it. Working further towards a plugin for Joomla to create an internal router.